# is it possible to undo jquery .html()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with a lot of stuff inside and using jquery I do

```
$("#section1").html('my new html stuff');
```

is it possible to undo this operation? just to avoid to put all the html in a variable an then do .html() again...

thanks

Comment: Nope. Save the original contents in a variable if you expect to need them again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in "undo" operation in JavaScript (or any language that I know of).  What you *can* do is preserve the previous state in a variable:

```
var previousState = $("#section1").html();
$("#section1").html('my new html stuff');
```

Now `previousState` holds what was in `#section1` before you replaced it.  If you want to revert it, you can:

```
$("#section1").html(previousState);
```

> just to avoid to put all the html in a variable an then do .html() again

I'm afraid that sort of custom state management is the job of the application developer, not the job of the language.  Imagine the overhead something like that would natively carry for the tiny fraction of applications which would actually use it.

Comment: Persisting raw markup won't preserve data and event handlers. You may want to use `clone()` as an alternative if that matters to you.